# How we can click UITableViewCell to jump into another View?

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard, xcode4.3

When I use storyboard in Xcode4 ,not as xib before, I click the `UITableViewCell` in `UITableView` to push View B，B have a tableView and other buttons and labels.
if the B inherit from `UIViewController`, when I push B,the background of B is black! 
if the B inherit `UITableViewController`, when I push B, the B shows the only table, other buttons and labels disappear!
I have connect the cell and B using push.
[image]
I want jump click the tablecell on the left View A into right View B.

what i want see is [image]

but when B inherits `UIViewController`and implement UITableViewDataSource and delegate,when jump into it,it shows [image]!!!

when i change B to inherit `UITableViewController`,it shows [image]

neither of it is what I want.......

Comment: this is a terribly worded question. Also, It's hard to know without seeing code....

Comment: Carefully reading your "question" shows that you clearly already have a segue or other method for moving between view controllers but your question asks "How to jump into another View?".  But your text indicates other issues like a black background or missing buttons / labels.  Can you please restate your question?